# Power Apps Office Add-in fails to retrieve environments

Tags: excel, powerapps, ms-office-addin

I'm having issues with the PowerApps Office Add-in for Excel. I'm unable to make a connection to my existing environments and it fails with error

> Call to retrieve environments available for user has failed. Details:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there nothing after "Details:"? At least it looks like there is a scrollbar.

Comment: just "error" is mentioned there